# Fixed Header Parallax Scrolling

Tags: html, scroll, parallax

I am trying to find out how to make a fixed header using parallax scrolling. 
I wish for each section (article) to have its own fixed header that slides up with the beginning of the slide, but stops at the very top until a new section is introduced.

And for each new section, attempting to have a separate title float top left, until the new section is introduced. The same concept as Facebook's fixed header, but only there during each parallax slide.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please expand your question so that it doesn't rely on people visiting the site you're working on? Depending on the link is strongly discouraged for reasons [described here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997/131713).

Comment: Lord torgamus, Thanks for that note, I wasn't aware. New here, and I'm glad you filled me in. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to use jquery Waypoints plugins. This sample might be what you need http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/sticky-elements/. You can create specific event when a section is reached or out from the viewport.

Comment: Thanks so much, let me give it a try!